# How to set "search" icon in the navigation tab bar in Ionic?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on an Ionic project and I want to set the "search" icon in the tab bar of my navigation. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<ion-tabs>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home" [rootParams]="apiuser"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Search" tabIcon="ion-md-search" [rootParams]="apiuser"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="Search" tabIcon="md-search" [rootParams]="apiuser"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab6Root" tabTitle="Search" tabIcon="search" [rootParams]="apiuser"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

The result:

[image]

I don't know why the icon is not displayed.

I've attempted to use various icon names such as `"ion-md-search"`, `"md-search"`, and `"search"` for the [tabIcon](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#tabs-icon-text) property, but none of them seem to work as expected. Can someone please provide guidance on how to correctly set the ["search" icon](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/ionicons/) in the tab bar of my Ionic application? My Ionic CLI version is 5.4.16, and I'm using Ionic Framework 3.9.4. I know that is very old version but i don't want to update it

---

The versions that I use:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16 
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.4-201903121725
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : not installed
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 23 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v14.18.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.15
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm install ionicons`
2. `import { Ionicons } from 'ionicons/icons';`
3. 

```
 <ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Search">
    <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
  </ion-tab>
  <!-- Other tabs -->
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: I update my question.The first tab is okay, but the others idk why there's nothin

Comment: I tried as you said with `<ion-icon>` but its not loading the image

Answer (score 0):

Use `ion-tab-bar` and `ion-tab-button`. something like this:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar>
    <ion-tab-button tab="search">
      <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label> Search </ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
     ....
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Ther's no <ion-tab-bar> for ionic v3